# create a filter in list fragment with custom adapter

Tags: android, search, fragment, custom-adapter

I implemented a filter to search my CustomAdapter.java

I add a link with a video tah explain my problem better of me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVzVeC7dZ-8

I have 2 problem:

1. Incorrect opening of the page after the filter
2. Incorrect loading of images on the list after the filter

HedlinesFragment.java

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment implements
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

String[] Headlines = {
        "Article One",
        "Article Two",
        "Article 3",
        "Article 4",
        "Article 5",
        "Article 6",
};

SearchView search_view;



OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

String[] menutitles;
TypedArray menuIcons;

CustomAdapter adapter;
private List<RowItem> rowItems;

// The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
    int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, null, false);











}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    menuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < menutitles.length; i++) {
        RowItem items = new RowItem(menutitles[i], menuIcons.getResourceId(
                i, -1));

        rowItems.add(items);
    }

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), (ArrayList<RowItem>) rowItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    search_view = (SearchView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText);
    search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(this);




}




@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
    // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment) != null) {
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Notify the parent activity of selected item
    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

    // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

Context context;
ArrayList<RowItem> rowItem;

ArrayList<RowItem> mStringFilterList;
ValueFilter valueFilter;




CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RowItem> rowItem) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItem = rowItem;
    mStringFilterList = rowItem;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return rowItem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return rowItem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return rowItem.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);

    RowItem row_pos = rowItem.get(position);
    // setting the image resource and title
    imgIcon.setImageResource(row_pos.getIcon());
    txtTitle.setText(row_pos.getTitle());

    Picasso
            .with(context)

            .load(Ipsum.url[position])
            .fit() // will explain later

            .centerCrop()
            .into(imgIcon);



    return convertView;

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<RowItem> filterList = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                if ( (mStringFilterList.get(i).getTitle().toUpperCase() )
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                    RowItem rowItem = new RowItem(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                            .getTitle() ,  mStringFilterList.get(i)
                            .getIcon()
                            );

                    filterList.add(rowItem);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        } else {
            results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
            results.values = mStringFilterList;
        }
        return results;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
        rowItem = (ArrayList<RowItem>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

RowItem.java

```
public class RowItem {

private String title;
private int icon;

public RowItem(String title, int icon) {
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;

}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}
```

Comment: I dont know if its this, but you are using 2 sources of data
RowItem row_pos = rowItem.get(position); 
and Picasso.load(Ipsum.url[position]); maybe they are not sincronized, you dont show all the code

.load(Ipsum.url[position])

Comment: I tried to remove this but nothing has changed .
my main problem , however, that when I do research and I app filters riusultati I opened the wrong relevant pages ( the still open in order) .
I added images to better understand !